# How do you create a general popup that can have many different types of dataproviders?

Tags: apache-flex, design-patterns, actionscript, adobe

If I have a flex component that is a general popup, it's basically just a white popup that I pass an Array named "modules" to.

For instance:

```
var array:Array = ["mainArticle","title"];
```

or

```
var array:Array = ["creditCard"];
```

These are two examples that I might pass in. The first one would add my modules to the popup so the popup will be used for editing an "article." The second would add the Credit Card Change module, which would be a form that would allow the user to update their credit card information.

My question resides in the dataProvider for this popup. If I am passing in the article updater, I need a dataProvider that contains information like "font," "color," "size," etc. If I am passing in the credit card updater, I need a dataProvider that contains information like "number," "securit code," "expiration date," etc.

I could have a dataProvider class that has all of the information and only sets what I need, but it could get huge if I did something like:

```
public class myDataProvider {
  public var mainTextFont:String;
  public var mainTextSize:int;
  public var mainText:String;

  public var cardNumber:String;
  public var cardExpiration:Date;
  public var cardSecurity:String;
}
```

This is sort of an abstract idea, but I am looking for a solution that allows me to give my popup dataproviders without using one central dataProvider that would have a copy for every possible situation.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you're approaching this all wrong.  You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't seem to exist...  Also, what's wrong with using CSS for style?

Comment: I'm not talking about myself displaying the text via CSS. Displaying it in a certain way is not what I am talking about. If a user puts their credit card information in, I need to store that. If they are updating their information, I need to pass that information to the popup to prepopulate the fields. In this case, I can either create specific popups(components) for each situation (credit card, user information, article editing, etc), but I would rather use one popup that loads different modules and gives each one it's own dataProvider.

Comment: ooookay.  And what's the difference between having the different popups and creating a module for each?  I doubt you'll be gaining anything is 'weight' to leverage modules.  If anything, just have a viewstack or something that switches depending on the situation and all the views have a data provider within it.  Again, you're creating a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: No, I see what you're saying. I don't have a problem, I am asking for an ideal solution/best practice. I don't feel I am portraying the question well. You're knowledgeable - I would love to email you, would you mind? (I can get it from your site).

Comment: I would prefer you keep it on the site so it can help other people.  There's no real general 'ideal solution' since this would be specific to your project, but if I were you, I'd create a popup 'container' that takes in data, and depending on that type of data (switch statement) instantiate the component related to the data and add it to the container, then add in the data to the component.  The component can then handle the data as it would normally.  Is that what you're going for?

Comment: Yes, right now I have a popup container that instantiates modules as I need them. I then pass the data to each module. This is where my question lasts, how to create the data. Should I create a different ADT for each module? Credit Card module needs different data then Article module, Save Draft module, Order placement module, etc. Should I create an ADT for each one, or should I create one "popupDataProvider" that can hold any of the modules information. The question is - one data provider class that has knowledge of everything, or a different data provider class for each case?

Comment: First, I wouldn't use modules (too much overhead for little reward, unless the popup is *huge*) and from there I would create a different model class (for all your data points). Your data provider set function would then do a switch statement to see what kind of data you have, which would then create an instance of the view you want, add it to the container, then do 'component.dataProvider = thatData;'.  I don't know how much clearer I can be without just doing it for you...

Comment: Yeah, when I said modules, I didn't mean actual "Modules." Just using that word to mean different pieces that are loaded at instantiation. Your answer is the kind of information I am looking for. You would recommend a sort of one-to-one relationship between view/model. I was tinkering with a 'wrapper' of sorts that can hold each piece of data, and I wasn't sure if it even made sense to go down that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to approach this is to create different dataProviders, depending on the class. My main popup has a "ModuleList" (custom list of strings) and it adds "modules" (not an actual flex module) to itself, giving each one the correct type of dataProvider.

```
public var recipientList:RecipientList;

private function setupModules():void {
  for each( var s:String in moduleList ){
    switch( s ){
      case 'recipients':
        var recipients:Recipients = new Recipients();
        recipients.list = recipientList;
        break;
      case 'article':
        // Article Logic
        break;
      case 'creditCard':
        // Credit Card Logic
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is just a generic idea, I was wondering what the best way to do this was, and this is how I decided to approach it.

Answer (score -1):

Would you consider use a generic Object class and wrap any param you need in the Object?

```
var data:Object = new Object();
data.mainTextFont = "";
data.mainTextSize= "";
data.mainText= "";
```

For component, you may also consider use "State" value to control the display/layout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure this is what I want. I would rather use some sort of ADT that is much more dynamic, while keeping named conventions that I have become accustom to.

Comment: Using dynamic properties will allow you to freely add any property values while keeping your preferred named conventions.

Comment: `public dynamic class myDataProvider {
    //Any fixed properties.
}`

Comment: Hmm... I had not thought about using a dynamic class. This is good, I wonder how I will be able to leverage this... I will put some thought into this.